# change pop up message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I change the popup message to have ok and cancel buttons?
Here is a link to my current code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ck4Fr/

Comment: What do you mean by that? Isn't it working now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmDu5/).

From the OP, I don't see anywhere that has an [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.alert) message or another type of pop-up, but if you are in fact using an [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.alert) for your pop-up you can change it to [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.confirm) instead.

Example:

```
alert("There is an error!");
```

vs

```
confirm("Continue anyway?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use `alert` or `confirm` dialog.

If you want to use customized popup then use [Jquery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)